# High memory/performance critical computing - Architectural approach opinions

Tags: node.js, t-sql, hadoop, parallel-processing, bigdata

I need an architectural opinion and approaches to the following problem:

### INTRO:

> We have a table of **`~4M`** rows called `Purchases`.
> We also have a table
>   of **`~5k`** rows called `Categories`.
> In addition, we have a table of
>   **`~4k`** `SubCategories`.
>  We are using T-SQL to store data.
> At users
>   request ( during runtime ), server receives a request of about **10-15** N
>   possibilities of parameters. Based on the parameters, we take
>   purchases, sort them by categories and subCategories and do some
>   computing.
> Some of the process of "computing" includes filtering,
>   sorting, rearranging fields of purchases, subtracting purchases with
>   each other, adding some other purchases with each other, find savings,
>   etc...
> This process is user specific, therefore every user WILL get
>   different data back, based on their roles.

### Problem:

> This process takes about 3-5 minutes and we are wanting to cut it
>   down.
> Previously, this process was done in-memory, on the browser via
>   webworkers (JS). We have moved away from it as the memory started to get
>   really large and most of browsers start to fail on load. Then we moved
>   the service to the server (NodeJS), which processed the request on the fly,
>   via child-processes. Reason for child-processes: the computing process
>   goes through a for loop about **5,000x** times ( for each category ) and does
>   the above mentioned "computing".
> Via child processes we were able to
>   distribute the work into #of child processes, which gave us somewhat
>   better results, if we ran at least 16-cores ( 16 child processes ).
>   Current processing time is down **to about a 1.5-2 minutes,** but we are
>   wanting to see if we have better options.

I understand its hard to fully understand our goals without seeing any code but to ask question specifically. What are some ways of doing computing on semi-big data at runtime?

Some thoughts we had:

1. using SQL in-memory tables and doing computations in sql
2. using azure batch services
3. using bigger machines ( ~ 32-64 cores, this may be our best shot if we cannot get any other thoughts. But of course, cost increases drasticaly, yet we accept the fact that cost will increase )
4. stepping into hadoop ecosystem ( or other big data ecosystems )

some other useful facts:

1. our purchases are about **~1GB** ( becoming a little too large for in-memory computing )
2. We are thinking of doing pre-computing and caching on redis to have SOME data ready for client ( we are going to use their parameters set in their account to pre-compute every day, yet clients tend to change those parameters frequently, therefore we have to have some efficient way of handling data that is NOT cached and pre-computed )

If there is more information we can provide to better understand our dilemma, please comment and I will provide as much info as possible. There would be too much code to paste in here for one to fully understand the algorithms therefore I want to try delivering our problem with words if possible.

Comment: How large are your purchases (memory footprint)?  Servers nowadays can support several TB of memory.  For example http://www.alphr.com/news/enterprise/387196/intel-xeon-e7-v2-servers-support-6tb-of-ram and NOTE: this article is 3 years old.

Comment: You might be interested in reading about Elastic Search https://www.elastic.co/

Answer (score 0):

### Never decide about technology before being sure about workflow's critical-path

This will never help you achieve ( a yet unknown ) target.

Not knowing the process critical-path, no one could calculate any speedup from whatever architecture one may aggressively-"sell" you or ***just***-"recommend" you to follow as "geeky/nerdy/sexy/popular" - whatever one likes to hear.

### What would you get from such pre-mature decision?

Typically a mix of both the budgeting ( co$t$ ) and Project-Management  ( sliding time-scales ) nightmares:

- additional costs ( new technology also means new skills to learn, new training costs, new delays for the team to re-shape and re-adjust and grow into a mature using of the new technology at performance levels better, than the currently used tools, etc, etc )
- risks of choosing a "popular"-brand, which on the other side does not exhibit any superficial powers the marketing texts were promising ( but once having paid the initial costs of entry, there is no other way than to bear the risk of never achieving the intended target, possibly due to overestimated performance benefits & underestimated costs of transformation & heavily underestimated costs of operations & maintenance )

### What would you say, if you could use a solution,
where "Better options" remain your options:

- you can start **now**, with the code you are currently using **without a single line of code changed**
- you can start **now** with a **still YOUR free-will based gradual path** of performance scaling
- you can avoid all risks of (mis)-investing into any extra-premium costs "super-box", but **rather stay on the safe side** re-use a cheap and massively in-service tested / fine-tuned / deployment-proven COTS hardware units ( a common dual-CPU + a few GB machines, commonly used in large thousands in datacentres )
- you can scale up to any level of performance you need, **growing CPU-bound processing performance gradually** from start, hassle-free, **up to some ~1k ~2k ~4k ~8k CPUs**, as needed -- yes, up to many thousands of CPUs, that your current workers'-code can immediately use for delivering the immediate benefit of the such increased performance and thus leave your teams free hands and more time for thorough work on possible design improvements and code re-factoring for even better performance envelopes if the current workflow, having been "passively" just smart-distributed to say ~1000, later ~2000 or ~5000-CPU-cores ( still without a single SLOC changed ) do not suffice on its own?
- you can scale up -- again, gradually, on an as-needed basis, hassle-free -- up to ( almost ) **any size of the in-RAM capacity, be it on Day 1 ~8TB, ~16TB, ~32TB, ~64TB**, jumping to **~72TB or ~128TB** next year, if needed -- all that keeping your budget always ( almost ) linear and fully adjusted by your performance plans and actual customer-generated traffic
- you can isolate and **focus your R&D efforts** not on (re)-learning "new"-platform(s), but **purely into process** (re)**-design for further increasing the process performance** ( be it using a strategy of pre-computing, where feasible, be it using smarter fully-in-RAM layouts for even faster ad-hoc calculations, that cannot be statically pre-computed )

### What would business owners say to such ROI-aligned strategy?

If one makes CEO + CFO "buy" any new toy, well, that is cool for hacking this today, that tommorrow, but such approach will never make shareholders any happier, than throwing ( their ) money into the river of Nile.

If one can show the ultimately efficient Project plan, where most of the knowledge and skills are focused on business-aligned target and at the same time protecting the ROI, that would make both your CEO + CFO and I guarantee that also all your shareholders very happy, wouldn't it?

So, which way would you decide to go?

Answer (score 0):

This topic isn't really new but just in case... As far as my experience can tell, I would say your T-SQL DB might by your bottle neck here.

Have you measured the performance of your SQL queries? What do you compute on SQL server side? on the Node.js side?

A good start would be to measure the response time of your SQL queries, revamp your queries, work on indexes and dig into how your DB query engine works if needed. Sometimes a small tuning in the DB settings does the trick!